# SQL Server Dynamic SQL with LIKE clause and SQL Injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection, dynamic-sql, sql-like

I'm having a dynamically built SQL as below. My question is, is it vulnerable to SQL Injection? If yes, how should I fix it?

```
  --search title only    
 if @SearchType =2    
 BEGIN     
  SET @strSQL = @strSQL + 'AND  (IDownload.FileTitle LIKE ''%'+@Search+'%''  ) '    
END
```

Comment: Yes, and it's fixable by using proper parameterisation for your dynamic SQL (e.g. using sp_executesql with @search as a parameter).

Comment: @ZLK what if my server side code (c#) is already using proper parameterisation & prepared statement, is my SQL Server code still vulnerable?

Comment: Yes, it's still vulnerable, because of the way the current statement is written.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, check:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (Id int)
GO

CREATE TABLE IDownload (FileTitle nvarchar(100))

DECLARE @strSQL nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Search nvarchar(max) = 'a'') DROP TABLE Test --'

SET @strSQL = 'SELECT 1 FROM IDownload WHERE 1 = 1 '

SET @strSQL = @strSQL + 'AND  (IDownload.FileTitle LIKE ''%'+@Search+'%''  ) '    

PRINT @strSQL
EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL

DROP TABLE IDownload
```

I can drop table `Test` passing special string in `@Search`. Rewrite your code using `sp_executesql` procedure and parameters.

Comment: But how should I rephrase the like statement to something which is SQL Injection proof? I've been looking over the internet and all the example seems to be similar as the one you have posted. I'm already using sp_executesql and paramdefinition in my code.